# static NSString for UITableViewCellIdentifier

Tags: iphone, objective-c, static

I'm looking at some code and was wondering how this works.  In one class, I see something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleCellIdentifier = @"SimpleCellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SimpleCellIdentifier"];
....
return cell
}
```

Then in another class, I'll see the same snippet for stock UITableViewCells.  I was wondering what happens to the

```
static NSString *simpleCellIdentifier;
```

Since it's static, it gets allocated for the lifetime of the project right?  So if the code in another viewController gets run, what happens?  Does it just use the old `simpleCellIdentifier` that was created in the other class?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case `simpleCellIdentifier` only exists within the method scope. So there can be as many `simpleCellIdentifier` in different methods as you like because they are different instances.

If you declare the `static` variable within the class scope, then you are working with the same instance whenever you read/write that variable in that class.